# chef-solo from_file had an error out bash /tmp/chef-script returned 1, expected 0

Tags: django, deployment, fabric, chef-infra, chef-recipe

Im having this error appear on chef-solo recipes, Im new to it so I dont really get this error or how to fix it... still sounds like either file or dir not found, created...

```
out: [Fri, 18 Mar 2011 15:59:28 +0000] ERROR: script[Install_Requirements] (/etc/chef/cookbooks/main/recipes/rincon.rb:35:in `from_file') had an error:
out: "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20110318-7369-1hi8q5e-0" returned 1, expected 0
```

This is the recipe that shows the error.

```
script "Install_Requirements" do
  interpreter "bash"
  user "rincon"
  group "rincon"
  cwd "/tmp"
  code <<-EOH
  /home/rincon/sites/rinconcolombia/bin/pip install -r /home/rincon/sites/rinconcolombia/checkouts/rinconcolombia/requirements.txt
  EOH
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ive been using chef-solo -l debug flag and its been giving me all the info I need to debug this problem... Thank you all hope this works for you should you find yourself in the same caveat